# HTML form is not working as expected, it is not like what i written

Tags: javascript, html

i have this form in a table:

```
<tr>
    <form action="/create" method="POST">
        <td class="align-middle">
            <button type="submit">save</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="newProductPrice">
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

but in the browser it looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <form action="/create" method="POST"></form>
    <td class="align-middle">
        <button type="submit">save</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" name="newProductPrice">
    </td>
</tr>
```

and it just made the whole thing go wrong

Comment: The next thing after tr tag always should be td tag

Comment: it looks same for me

Comment: That's because your HTML is invalid and the browser is trying to fix it. Also, don't use tables for layout, use CSS

Comment: @j08691 i have to becuase it is used with dataTables and using tables just make the whole work easier

Comment: You should not put another tag between tr and td. Use div instead of the tr/td.

Answer (score 0):

The only allowed immediate child elements of a `<tr>` are `<th>` and `<td>`. Your browser is doing it's best to handle that, by "correcting" the markup to closest valid version.

If you insist on trying to make this work, the closest you can probably get requires using the [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefform) attribute on either the button or the input, with the other element being contained within a valid form. Something like

```html
<tr>
    <td class="align-middle">
        <button type="submit" form="the-form">save</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form action="/create" method="POST" id="the-form">
            <input type="number" name="newProductPrice">
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If you go this route, each form must have a unique id attribute (which would be true regardless, since ids must be unique anyway) for each row.